# CNN with Embeddings - high trainings accuracy and stable validation accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a cnn on word embeddings. I have balanced the labels and resampled the dataset. Nevertheless I get a training accuray of about 1 and a stable validation accuray. I have also tried with a higher batch side, but the result did not change. Also I tried with a lower learning rate, but this did  not change  the result as well. Since the model is about 30% correct in the validation, I think that the model simply always estimates the same label.

The training data looks like that:

```
print(X_train)
54385    [[0.12353599816560745, -0.0795464739203453, 0....
48435    [[0.010086433961987495, -0.0011868071742355824...
35293    [[0.12353599816560745, -0.0795464739203453, -0...
62803    [[0.12353599816560745, -0.0795464739203453, -0...
28509    [[0.12353599816560745, -0.0795464739203453, -0...
                               ...                        
14816    [[0.010086433961987495, -0.0011868071742355824...
15135    [[0.12353599816560745, -0.0795464739203453, 0....
16600    [[0.12353599816560745, -0.0795464739203453, -0...
24827    [[0.12353599816560745, -0.0795464739203453, -0...
59745    [[0.010086433961987495, -0.0011868071742355824...
Name: Text_Vector, Length: 91859, dtype: object


X_train_3dtensor = tf.stack(list(X_train), axis=0)
X_train = None
del(X_train)
X_train_3dtensor = tf.transpose(X_train_3dtensor, [0, 2, 1])
X_train_4dtensor = tf.expand_dims(X_train_3dtensor, -1) 
X_train_4dtensor.get_shape()
TensorShape([91859, 20, 300, 1])
```

And the Labels like:

```
print(y_test)
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]]
```

Model

```
num_filters = 30
filter_sizes = [3,4,5]

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(20,300,1,), name="input_layer")

con_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[0], 300))(input_layer)
relu_3 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_3 )

con_4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[1], 300))(input_layer)
relu_4 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_4 )

con_5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[2], 300))(input_layer)
relu_5 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_5 )


max_3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_3.get_shape()[1] , 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_3)
max_4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_4.get_shape()[1] , 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_4)
max_5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_5.get_shape()[1] , 1), strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_5)


merged = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([max_3,max_4, max_5])
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(merged)
dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(flatten)

dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, name="dense_layer_4")(dropout)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(name="output_layer")(dense_layer)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, output_layer, name="model")
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01),
               metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])



 model.fit(X_train_4dtensor,y_train , epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data(X_test_4dtensor,y_test))

Epoch 1/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 72s 25ms/step - loss: 0.0045 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9992 - val_loss: 113.2618 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 2/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 73s 25ms/step - loss: 6.2454e-05 - categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 112.7601 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 3/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 73s 25ms/step - loss: 6.3919e-04 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9999 - val_loss: 102.1906 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 4/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 73s 25ms/step - loss: 0.0016 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9998 - val_loss: 158.6906 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 5/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 72s 25ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9999 - val_loss: 160.3155 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 6/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 72s 25ms/step - loss: 3.1164e-04 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9999 - val_loss: 160.3133 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 7/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 72s 25ms/step - loss: 5.1186e-04 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9999 - val_loss: 160.3161 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 8/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 72s 25ms/step - loss: 5.0507e-04 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9999 - val_loss: 160.3165 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 9/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 73s 25ms/step - loss: 4.1438e-04 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9999 - val_loss: 160.3167 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
Epoch 10/10
2871/2871 [==============================] - 72s 25ms/step - loss: 4.5932e-04 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9999 - val_loss: 160.3223 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3290
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f095a128550>
```

I changed the convolution layer to 1D thanks to the hint from @Matus Dubrava. Now the training accuracy is improving with every epoch. Unfortunately, the validation accuracy keeps the same consistently. In the test dataset the model seems to estimate always the same label. But not in the training dataset.

```
num_filters = 30
filter_sizes = [3,4,5]

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(300,20,1,), name="input_layer")

con_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[0]))(input_layer)
relu_3 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_3 )

con_4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[1]))(input_layer)
relu_4 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_4 )

con_5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[2]))(input_layer)
relu_5 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_5 )


max_3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_3.get_shape()[1] ,
                                             con_3.get_shape()[2]), 
                                  strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_3)
max_4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_4.get_shape()[1] ,
                                             con_4.get_shape()[2]),
                                  strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_4)
max_5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_5.get_shape()[1] ,
                                             con_5.get_shape()[2] ), 
                                  strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_5)


merged = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([max_3,max_4, max_5])
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(merged)
dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(flatten)

dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, name="dense_layer_4")(dropout)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(name="output_layer")(dense_layer)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, output_layer, name="model")
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.00001),
               metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),'accuracy'])
model.summary()


Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)        [(None, 300, 20, 1)] 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)                 (None, 300, 18, 30)  120         input_layer[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)               (None, 300, 17, 30)  150         input_layer[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)               (None, 300, 16, 30)  180         input_layer[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu (ReLU)                    (None, 300, 18, 30)  0           conv1d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_1 (ReLU)                  (None, 300, 17, 30)  0           conv1d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_2 (ReLU)                  (None, 300, 16, 30)  0           conv1d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 1, 1, 30)     0           re_lu[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 30)     0           re_lu_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 30)     0           re_lu_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 3, 1, 30)     0           max_pooling2d[0][0]              
                                                                 max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
                                                                 max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 90)           0           concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 90)           0           flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_layer_4 (Dense)           (None, 3)            273         dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
output_layer (Softmax)          (None, 3)            0           dense_layer_4[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 723
Trainable params: 723
Non-trainable params: 0




model.fit(X_train_4dtensor,y_train , epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test_4dtensor, y_test))

Epoch 1/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 593s 207ms/step - loss: 1.1649 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3291  - val_loss: 1.0945 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334 
Epoch 2/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 611s 213ms/step - loss: 1.1313 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3482  - val_loss: 1.0866 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334 
Epoch 3/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 611s 213ms/step - loss: 1.1080 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3692  - val_loss: 1.0798 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334 
Epoch 4/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 613s 214ms/step - loss: 1.0877 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3910  - val_loss: 1.0724 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334 
Epoch 5/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 619s 215ms/step - loss: 1.0681 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4209  - val_loss: 1.0669 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334 
Epoch 6/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 616s 215ms/step - loss: 1.0495 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4473  - val_loss: 1.0601 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334 
Epoch 7/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 613s 214ms/step - loss: 1.0309 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4769  - val_loss: 1.0545 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334 
Epoch 8/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 612s 213ms/step - loss: 1.0140 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5055 - val_loss: 1.0490 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334
Epoch 9/100
2871/2871 [==============================] - 574s 200ms/step - loss: 0.9983 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5319 - val_loss: 1.0440 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3334
```

**Final**

```
num_filters = 60
filter_sizes = [3,4,5]
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(20,1,), name="input_layer")
emb_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 300)(input_layer)
emb = tf.transpose(emb_layer,[0,1,3,2])

con_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[0]))(emb)
relu_3 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_3 )

con_4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[1]))(emb)
relu_4 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_4 )

con_5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(num_filters, (filter_sizes[2]))(emb)
relu_5 =tf.keras.layers.ReLU()(con_5 )


max_3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_3.get_shape()[1] ,
                                             con_3.get_shape()[2]), 
                                  strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_3)
max_4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_4.get_shape()[1] ,
                                             con_4.get_shape()[2]),
                                  strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_4)
max_5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(con_5.get_shape()[1] ,
                                             con_5.get_shape()[2] ), 
                                  strides=(1,1), padding='valid')(relu_5)


merged = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([max_3,max_4, max_5])
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(merged)
dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(flatten)

dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=3, name="dense_layer_4")(dropout)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Softmax(name="output_layer")(dense_layer)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(input_layer, output_layer, name="model")
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
               metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
model.summary()


Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)        [(None, 20, 1)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)           (None, 20, 1, 300)   3000000     input_layer[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Transpose (TensorFl [(None, 20, 300, 1)] 0           embedding[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)                 (None, 20, 298, 60)  240         tf_op_layer_Transpose[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)               (None, 20, 297, 60)  300         tf_op_layer_Transpose[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)               (None, 20, 296, 60)  360         tf_op_layer_Transpose[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu (ReLU)                    (None, 20, 298, 60)  0           conv1d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_1 (ReLU)                  (None, 20, 297, 60)  0           conv1d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_2 (ReLU)                  (None, 20, 296, 60)  0           conv1d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 1, 1, 60)     0           re_lu[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 60)     0           re_lu_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 60)     0           re_lu_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 3, 1, 60)     0           max_pooling2d[0][0]              
                                                                 max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
                                                                 max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 180)          0           concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 180)          0           flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_layer_4 (Dense)           (None, 3)            543         dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
output_layer (Softmax)          (None, 3)            0           dense_layer_4[0][0]              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 3,001,443
Trainable params: 3,001,443
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Your model is too complex for the task that you are trying to solve (it has too many degrees of freedom). This is an extreme case of overfitting where your model is just memorizing every training input/output pair. Maybe if you provided more information about what you are trying to solve and a model reference architecture because word embedding are usually used together with 1D convolutions.

Comment: @MatusDubrava I will try it with 1d as well. I am trying to do a sentiment analysis. The model structure is based on https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D14-1181.pdf. 
As far as I understand Kim he also uses 2d conv. In my case every sentence is represented by a 20*300 matrix. Each column is a word. If I used 1d, would I not lose information about the word order?

Comment: They are using 1d convolutions in the paper. Also `Each column is a word` - I don't think so. Normally, you would have a word embedded into a 300d plane - which means that each column is a component of that 300d vector while each row is a word.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have somehow always thought of the words as rows. I will try it with 1d

Comment: @MatusDubrava  I changed the code to 1D conv. In my mind, the categorical_accuracy looks better, but the val_categorical_accuracy is always the same. I added the code in the original post.

Comment: It is hard for me to debug it without knowing what data you are feeding into the model. Here are some things to think about (1) Were the word embeddings build on a similar corpus to the one that you are using? (2) Have you correctly built the training and the validation set (is the training set representative enough)? (3) Do you even have enough data for such a complex model? (4) if everything else seems correct: is your model still overfitting? If so, then try increasing regularization until it stops overfitting.

Comment: @MatusDubrava Thanks, your hints were really helpful. Bevor I used fasttext to create the embeddings. Now I integreated the embeddings inside the model. Over that, I optimized the learning rate and batch size. After that, the model is not good, but the behavior seems realistic.